Defining events when solving conditional probability questions
Note this is a duplicate question and while they have the answers to the problem, none of them discuss why the following argument doesn't make sense
Question: This is from Blitzstein's Intro to Probability Book:
A bag contains one marble which is either green or blue, with equal probabilities. A
green marble is put in the bag (so there are 2 marbles now), and then a random marble
is taken out. The marble taken out is green. What is the probability that the remaining
marble is also green?
I am having some trouble defining my events properly. I defined them as follows:
$A$ is the event that the remaining marble is green, $B$ is the event that the marble taken out is green, $C$ is the event that the marble taken out was the original marble in the bag, so $C^C$ is the event that the marble taken out was the green marble put into the bag.

Using LOTP with extra conditioning, we get: $P(A|B) = P(A|B,C)P(C|B) + P(A|B,C^C)(P(C^C|B)$. The requirement for this in this case would be $P(C \cap B)>0$ and $P(C^C \cap B)>0$ which they are (I think).
$P(A|B,C)$ = probability remaining marble is green given you took out a green marble that was the original marble in the bag = $1$.
$P(C|B)$ = probability marble taken out was the marble in the bag originally given the marble taken out is green = probability original marble was green * probability you took it out = $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$. (I suspect something is wrong with this step since I am assuming independence?)
$P(A|B,C^C)$ = probability remaining marble is green given you took out a green marble that was the new green marble put into the bag = $\frac{1}{2}$.
$P(C^C|B)$ = probability marble taken out was the new marble put into the bag given the marble taken out is green = probability of taking the new marble out of the bag = $\frac{1}{2}$.
So my answer is $1*\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ which is wrong.

As I mentioned at the start of my post, I know I haven't chosen the best events to condition on (the solutions said that my event $C$ should have been the event that the initial marble is green) but I am just trying to understand why my method didn't work.
Thank You.

this problem is well known, attributed to Lewis Carroll.    I suggest reviewing the standard arguments for it, as in the duplicate.

I have already but I don't understand where I am going wrong with my argument

Step $#3$ is wrong, or at least incomplete, because you identify the conditional probability with the probability of the intersection without justifying that.

I have now edited my question. ALso could you provide more detail as to how step 3 is wrong

As I say, the problem is a duplicate.  I suggest reviewing the existing proofs and comparing those to what you wrote.  As for step $#3$, $P(C,|,B)$ is a Bayes' Theorem computation.  By definition, it is $\frac {P(C\cap B)}{P(B)}$.

yes while the question is a duplicate, i have thoroughly checked the answers and none of them explain my problem
